# WooCommerce: Possible to Sell Links To Youtube Videos, Hidden Pages, etc.?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce I set my product to "Downloadable" and "Virtual", but it appears that I can only use links for downloadable files.  The question is, can I somehow use any URL, such as youtube video or a hidden page on my site as my product? Is there a plugin that can be used?  TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sell acces to stream only (or stream and download) video, one option you could look at is using this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-hss-extension-for-streaming-video/

It integrates woocommerce with a streaming video platform but does involve paying a monthly fee starting at $7/month.

Comment: Thank you! The client went with "GoToWP Premium Woo" which is a bit different than the original question, but this plugin is exactly what I was looking for at the time.

Answer (score 1):

For selling access to live streams/ video on demand you can check this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpstream/  or wpstream.net . It also works with WooCommerce and Woocommerce Subscriptions (see the videos)